# Как настроить обновление страницы при окончании воспроизведения аудио

Tags: javascript, php, html, аудио, обновление

Как можно реализовать обновление страницы которое будет происходить сразу после того как закончилось воспроизведение музыки? На странице audio из mysql

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events. Встроенные с помощью HTML тегов <audio> или <video> медиа объекты генерируют различные события. Есть событие ended -отправляется, когда воспроизведение завершено